# How can i get the lat long value by plugin than call web service in ionic in angular 5?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geocode

I am trying to find out lat long by giving places by geocode in angular 5 in ionic framework.  After finding the lat long i m trying to call my service by passsing the lat long in the service.

the problem is that my service gets called before the plugin call,hence I get the value of lat long as undefined.

```
//this is the plugin
    selectSearchResult(item) {
        var address =item.description;
        this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == 'OK') {
            this.formatted_address=results[0].formatted_address;
            console.log(this.formatted_address);
             this.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             this.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
           }
         });
    ////this is my service
         this.fetch.GetLocation(this.latitude,this.longitude).subscribe(
          result => {
            console.log(result);
          },
          err =>{
            console.error("Error : "+err);
          } ,
          () => {
            console.log('getData completed');
          }
        );
       }
```

how can i call the plugin before my web service ??

Answer (score 0):

For your code can try below:

```
selectSearchResult = (item) => {
        var address =item.description;
        this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
            this.formatted_address=results[0].formatted_address;
            console.log(this.formatted_address);
             this.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             this.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
             //web service function call
             this.serviceFun();
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
           }
        });
    } 

    serviceFun = () => {
     this.fetch.GetLocation(this.latitude,this.longitude).subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
      },
      err =>{
        console.error("Error : "+err);
      } ,
      () => {
        console.log('getData completed');
      }
    );
   }
```

Comment: yah i used this plugin but i want to call my web service after getting the lat long.

Comment: yes thanks..but i dn't want current location..i want user selected location lat long.

Comment: thanks... i m gettign this error : Uncaught TypeError: this.serviceFun is not a function

Comment: Missed a curly close bracket at end of selectSearchResult function. Updated answer. Also, make sure your both functions are in the same file.